# Ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For convention: homomorphism take unity to unity. I believe, please check if correct, there is not Ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let's prove it, let $f$ be the homomorphism, then:

First recall $f(-1)=-1$ (happens for any ring, in fact for $+$, any ring is a group, and that is true for groups). Then:

$$-1=f(-1)=f(ii)=f(i)f(i) \geq 0$$

So $-1 \geq 0$ absurd.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the most immediate way to solve it. I think you can also directly take for granted that $x^2=-1$ has no solutions in $\Bbb R$, without need to explicitly prove it.

Comment: i.e. the hom would map the root $\,x=i\,$ of $x^2+1$  to a  root in $\Bbb R$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot say that $f(-1)=-1$ happens for every ring homomorphism. There is one homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{R}$:

For every $a \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, $f(a)=f(a\cdot 1)=f(a)\cdot f(1)$ so $f(a)(1-f(1))=0$. This means that for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, $f(a)=0$ or $f(1)=1$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is an integral domain.

If $f(1)=1$, then we can properly say that $f(-1)=-1$ and your argument become valid.

Otherwise,

\begin{align*}
  f \colon  \mathbb{Z}[i] &\to \mathbb{R} \\  a &\mapsto 0 
  \end{align*}

is a homomorphism since for all $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, $f(a+b)=0=0+0=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(a\cdot b)=0=0\cdot 0=f(a)\cdot f(b)$. It is also the only homomorphism possible between $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your homomorphism depends on the definition of what is an homomorphism. If we demand the morphisms to be unitary, then your $f$ is not an homomorphism.

Comment: Sorry dude, I forgot to specify that a requirement for homomorphism is taking unity to unity, now I edited the post at the beggining. Your answer actually is excelent, I encourage to keep it like that, my mistake was to forget to ask about homopshims taking unity to unity, but you still adressed, keep the good work.